# iOS 5 or iOS 4 upload to YouTube?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube, google, google-apps

I have iPhone4 running iOS 5.1. No, I will not upgrade to iOS6 because it will delete my beloved pre-installed Maps application, and the new one from Google is [snip...] ... not performing up to my expectations.

I also have an iPhone3G running iOS 4.2. This cannot be upgraded at all.

I had used the pre-installed YouTube app to upload videos in the past. Everything worked flawlessly. Now, this app no longer accepts my Google login. Yes, I've read about 2-step login process. I've tried that. Worked everywhere, but on the pre-installed YouTube app. Google is purposely blocking that app because [reasons].

An older version of Google's native YouTube app from Appstore (the latest one requires iOS6 that I cannot install) has no way to upload. It recommends to download YouTube Capture App. I try that... and it needs iOS6.

Someone please tell me how to upload to YouTube from iOS5 and iOS4.2 considering that pre-installed YouTube app cannot login anymore.

Comment: Could you edit the rants out of this and focus on what you want to do as opposed to clouding the story by what you feel is the motivation of large companies and presumably some subset of the employees that work for those companies?

Comment: I want to upload to YouTube from an old iOS. It is as clear now in the "rant-and-motivation-free" edit as it was in the original.

Answer (score -1):

I upload through the Safari browser. You have to be in desktop view, but it works every time for me.

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail how you do this with the Safari in iOS 5?